# Print Dialog shows correct number of page, however final number of pages printed are less

Tags: java, awt

I am looking into very old code, which takes an AWT Book object and prints it.

Print dialog opens and show correct number of pages. Pressing ok starts the actual printing, but printer properties shows spooling of less number of pages and prints.

log.info prints the same number of pages shown in print dialog.

Code snippet is very straight forward-

```
  final PrinterJob pj = printJob;
  final Book b = book;

  log.info("Number of pages " + b.getNumberOfPages() );
  Runnable r = new Runnable()
  {
    public void run()
    {
      pj.setPageable(b);

      if (pj.printDialog())
      {
        try
        {
          pj.print();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          new CError(ex.getMessage()).show(true);
        }
      }
    }
  };
  new Thread(r).start();
```

any direction where should I look to resolve this?